# Output CSV file encoding is incorrect UTF-8

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, encoding

I have UTF-8 (no BOM) encoded CSV file:

```
aaa;bbb;ccc
fff;äää;ööö
```

Following snippet reads the the file and then saves it again using different encoding:

```
import csv

rows = []
with open('test_in.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in csvReader:
        rows.append(row)

with open('test_out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in rows:
        csvWriter.writerow(row)
```

**Problem:** Saved file is not iso-8859-1, but utf-8 encoded.

If I replace the file read with following list in my UTF-8 encoded source code file, it works correctly:

```
rows = [
    ['aaa','bbb','ccc'],
    ['fff','äää','ööö']
]
```

Is this a bug in Python?  Or do I have to use additional encoding options?

Tested with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `encoding` option for `open()` doesn't work as I thought (I assumed it defaults to UTF-8). Docs for [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) say:

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. **The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)**, but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. ...

And on my system it seems to default to *cp1252*. Thus `repr(rows)` returns

```
[['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['fff', 'Ã¤Ã¤Ã¤', 'Ã¶Ã¶Ã¶']]
```

Fix is to explicitly specify encoding also for the input file:

```
with open('test_in.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with python3.5.1 and it worked fine for me:

```
sharad@ss:~$ rm test_out.csv
sharad@ss:~$ ls test_in.csv
test_in.csv
sharad@ss:~$ cat my.py
import csv

rows = []
#with open('my.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
with open('test_in.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    csvReader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in csvReader:
        rows.append(row)

with open('test_out.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='iso-8859-1') as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in rows:
        csvWriter.writerow(row)
sharad@ss:~$
sharad@ss:~$ python3.5 my.py
sharad@ss:~$ ls test_out.csv
test_out.csv
sharad@ss:~$ file test_*.csv
test_in.csv:  UTF-8 Unicode text
test_out.csv: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
sharad@ss:~$
```